# Efficient algorithm for factorizing symbolic sum of products

Tags: term-rewriting, computer-algebra, prolog

Given a sum of flat symbolic products like $axc + byc + ayc + bxc$, how can I efficiently factorize it as a product of sums like $(a+x)(b+y)c$? For my problem, the products are not commutative -- it's more like a sum-of-tuples becoming a tuple-of-sums.

**What have I tried**:
So far, I have this Prolog program ([run in Swish](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/factorize.pl)). It is not able to handle a case with more than two terms in a sum, tough.

```
% factor(Sum, Product)
% Common factor (from left or right).
factor(T*X+T*Y, T*F) :-
  factor(X+Y, F).
factor(X*T+Y*T, F*T) :-
  factor(X+Y, F).

% No common factor (from left or right), recurse into sub-expressions
factor(T1*X+T2*Y, (T1*A+T2*B)*C) :-
  factor(X, A*C),
  factor(Y, B*C).
factor(X*T1+Y*T2, C*(A*T1+B*T2)) :-
  factor(X, C*A),
  factor(Y, C*B).

% Base case, no factorization.
factor(T, T).
```

I've also tried an imperative implementation that firsts sorts the terms, then factor pairs that have a single different term. It does `n` passes on the list of products, where `n` is the maximum size of the product:

```
Pass #1:
a*x*c + a*y*c + b*x*c + b*y*c
 \        /       
 a*(x+y)*c

 a*(x+y)*c + b*x*c + b*y*c 
      \       /
     differ by more
    than one element

 a*(x+y)*c + b*x*c + b*y*c 
                \      /
               b*(x+y)*c

 Pass #2:
 a*(x+y)*c + b*(x+y)*c
     \           /
     (a+b)*(x+y)*c
```

This implementation, on the other hand, can't factorize terms that have just one term in common, like `a*x*c + b*y*c = (a*x+b*y)*c`. The full code can be run [in this Repl.it](https://repl.it/@Bruno_KimKim1/FactorizingSumOfProducts); please let me know if it should be in the body of the question.

**Context**: I'm implementing a static type analyser that derives the concrete types of a generic function from its calls. So, a function `a -> b -> Bool` that is called with `Int -> Int -> Bool` and `Str -> Str -> Bool` would have type `(Int -> Int)|(Str -> Str) -> Bool`.

Comment: Are you only interested in factors that are a sum of single symbols, or might it be a sum of products of symbols?  For instance, could $(a+xy)(bc+x)$ be a valid factorization of some term?

Comment: That's an interesting factorization for me, yes. It may correspond to a function with types `Float64|(Float64 -> Float64)`, which is actually seen in Python scientific packages where you can provide a constant value $w$ or a generating function $w_i = f(x_i)$.