# Can equations be simplified with the help of a given set of equations?

Tags: reference-request, computer-algebra

There are many posts here and elsewhere asking for algorithms to simplify simple arithmetic expressions. For example, [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133534/125765) asks how to simplify the expression $axc + byc + ayc + bxc$. [Symbolics](https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/dev/) and [xcas](http://xcas.sourceforge.net/en/) are two examples [among many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) of Computer Algebra Systems (CAS) that can do this. But Symbolics and xcas perform differently: Symbolics can simplify the expression above and turn it into $cx(a + b) + cy(a + b)$, whereas xcas completely factorizes the expression into $(a + b)c(x + y)$.

I was wondering if there is any CAS that simplifies expressions based on some set of equations that you can input into the system? As an example, assume that we knew $a + b = 2$ and $x + y = -1$: is there any known (implemented) algorithm that given said equations, would factorize the expression above into simply $-2c$ ? Perhaps it's more pertinent to ask: could such an algorithm exist?

In the example above, we can set $y = -1 - x$ and $b = 2 - a$ (as pointed out in a comment), but in more complicated examples it might not be possible.

Comment: Not sure the this is what you want, but setting $b:=2-a$ and $y:=-1-x$ will give you the desired simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your knowledge is in the form of linear equations, as in your example, then you can make a simple substitution.  In your example, set $b=2-a$ and $y=-1-x$, as [Yves Daoust suggests](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154304/can-equations-be-simplified-with-available-knowledge#comment324392_154304).  This will work for any system of linear equations.

If the expression is a polynomial and the "knowledge" is expressed as equations of polynomials, then it is possible that [Groebner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) might be useful - I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I didn't explain that I also might use non-linear equations.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because I can see the question is too broad and perhaps I'm not using the right terminology. Thanks!